# Everytime i open new file and click anywhere in object mode it pops up "cannot read file"

Tags: object-mode

[image]

It mentions about previous file which I deleted but it is an opened new file. Every time i click it pops up `cannot read file` well colored part is to hide my identity but next part reads "i am the cure. blend" which is deleted. The problem i am facing is i cannot select object at all or can not join different objects.

Answer (score 1):

Finally after a long time i got the solution of my problem actually the solution seems to be pretty simple . first we have to go to prefernces present in edit option .[image]

later in preferences at the bottom 3 columns icon is there after clicking it 4 options pop ups but for us 2 are main 1) load factory preferences 2) save prefernces . first click on load factory preferences later on save preferences afterward close it i suggest to click ctrl s also .[image]

[image]

here is the final result no pop ups at all after clicking also i can select objects with no problem .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the startup file located in C:\Users<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender<blender version>\config\startup.blend

Comment: It already says cannot read file so it is obvious that file is deleted right ?

Comment: It created new problem now it pops up save don't save cancel

Comment: startup.blend ? where to find it ?

Comment: Problem is in object mode + edit mode  only there I am finding this stuff not in sculpting mode .

Comment: bro pls help . atleast tell different sites to approach where i may find some solution

Comment: pls bro i really need help

Comment: By the way are you using windows ? if yes try renaming the folder C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender<blender version>\ and relaunch blender.

Comment: Can you post answer with images so that it makes clear to me where to type such thing and restart blender again ? Video or photo anything ?

Comment: what version of blender are you using ?

Comment: 3.6.2.0 earlier one was 3.3.1.0

Comment: Right now it is 3.6.2.0

Comment: ok and same problem with 3.3 and 3.6 ?

Comment: Yes brother actually I am bit sick but so I replied late . Sorry

Comment: what is your windows user name ?

Comment: Come on man how I can tell that? Why would I reveal my identity?

Comment: Can't you show through your laptop ? Or computer by hiding ur identity pls  brother ?

Comment: Like I marked green colour